# Where to put a Mixin that's used by multiple apps?

Tags: django

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but I have a mixin I want to use in multiple apps.

Is there a best practice on where this mixin should go?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a file mixins.py in your utils/ folder and use it your apps.

Comment: I do that too, but prefer to call it `common` (+1).

Answer (score 1):

I would create an app which includes the Mixin and rely on this app in all those multiple apps which should use the Mixin. A short example as i don't know the purpose of your Mixin:

If you want to write a Mixin which is related to authentication i would recommend to create an app call `myauth` (where `my` should be some other prefix)- put the Mixin there and all other apps will rely on `myauth` in this case. `myauth` might later also include other pieces related to authentication.

If this Mixin will be the only thing you want to reuse in other apps you might just create a non specifiy purpose app like `mygeneralpurposelibs` and put it there together with stuff necessary for completely different purposes.

I prefer the topic related apps like `myauth` instead of the lib buckets. As usual the final app structure relies on your specific needs.